# How do I get a string representation of an image before uploading?

Tags: python, image, google-app-engine, blobstore

I'm trying to intercept an image from an HTML form's input control to convert it into a byte string before processing it on the server side.

**How do I intercept the file?**

```
upload_files = self.get_uploads('file')
# Intercept here to do something different than just upload 
blob_info = upload_files[0]
```

**How do I convert it into a byte string that can be converted back to an image later?**

I'm using Python and App Engine.

Comment: base64? http://docs.python.org/library/base64.html

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking - the code you quote is server side, so when you run it the image has already been uploaded. And, an image _is_ a byte string.

Comment: you already have an bytestring... you just have to store it in a blob property..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5211780/store-jpg-gif-png-etc-it-gae-datastore/5217869#5217869

Comment: Thank you all for the comments. I think I have to understand a bit more about images - this is my first foray. To help me get going, if I were to do str(blob_info), would it return the string rep of a base64 string like using str(urlfetch(url).result.content)? I can post this as a separate question if you feel I should.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume your upload control is in a form named "image" and you are using [Werkzeug's FileStorage](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/datastructures/):

```
img_stream = self.form.image.data
mimetype = img_stream.content_type
img_str = img_stream.read().encode('base64').replace('\n', '')

data_uri = 'data:%s;%s,%s' % (mimetype, 'base64', img_str)
```

Your [data_uri](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme#HTML) now contains the string information you need.

*Thank you all for your helpful comments!*